# Ajax to do replace of HTML in a tab

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, joomla

I need some experience help here. I am not sure how to do it and totally blur.

I am using joomla and I have li tab with onclick="get_db()" function.

```
<li><a href="#addpanel3" data-toggle="tab" onclick="get_db()"><s1><?php echo Jtext::_('ST_OTHER_INFORMATION');?></s1></a></li>
```

The function to get_db() is here

```
function get_db()
    {
    var live_site = '<?php echo JURI::root()?>';
    var catid = document.getElementById('category_id');
    var tabcatid = catid.value;
    alert(tabcatid);
    loadSubFeatureinfo(tabcatid,live_site);
    }
```

get_db() function then calls for loadSubFeatureinfo(tabcatid,live_site) in ajax.js with the following codes

```
function loadSubFeatureinfo(tabcatid,live_site){
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlHttp==null){
         alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
        return
        }
    url = live_site + "index.php?option=com_osproperty&no_html=1&tmpl=component&task=ajax_loadfeainfo" + "&tabcatid=" + tabcatid;
//alert(url);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=ajax4gfea;
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
    xmlHttp.send(null)
}

function ajax4gfea() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){ 
    res = xmlHttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("subfeature_div").innerHTML = res;      
    } 
}
```

After that it calls for ajax_loadfeainfo in ajax.php

```
case "ajax_loadfeainfo":
$tabcatid = JRequest::getVar('tabcatid','');
OspropertyAjax::loadSubfeature($option,$tabcatid);
break;
```

Then to the function loadSubfeature($option,$tabcatid) in ajax.php

```
function loadSubfeature($option,$tabcatid){
global $mainframe;
@header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo $tabcatid;
    if($tabcatid == 1){ 
    echo 'This is tab 1 front';
                ?>
                        <?php   
                            if(count($groups) > 0){
                            for($i=0;$i<count($groups);$i++){
                                $group = $groups[$i];
                                $fields = $group->fields;
                                if(count($fields) > 0){

                                    echo JHtml::_('sliders.panel', $group->group_name,strtolower(str_replace(" ","",$group->group_name)));      
                                    ?>
                                    <table  width="100%" class="admintable">
                                    <tr>
                                    <?php
                                    $m = 0;
                                    for($j=0;$j<count($fields);$j++){
                                        $m++;
                                        $field = $fields[$j];
                                        if($field->required == 1){
                                            $require_field .= $field->field_name.",";
                                            $require_label .= $field->field_label.",";
                                        }
                                        ?>

                                            <td class="key" style="padding-top:4px;">
                                                <span class="hasTip" title="<?php echo $field->field_label?>::<?php echo $field->field_description?>">
                                                    <?php echo $field->field_label?>Hello
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="bottom">
                                                <?php
                                                HelperOspropertyFields::showField($field,$row->id);
                                                ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <?php
                                                if($m == 2){
                                                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                                                $m = 0;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>

                                        </tr>
                                    <!--    <?php  
                                    } 
                                    ?>-->  
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- End of Addition by Jerry -->
                                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php   

    }
    exit;
}
```

What I am trying to do here is to have html generated to replace another html in the main page when get_db() is called, but It is not working.

I try to echo out the variable into my page and it works. However the html codes are not sent to replace the original html.

I am a rookie programmer and i am not sure if i am doing right or not. I just need to replace the orginal html codes in a section of my page with the html generated by ajax.php and show the result i want.

Can anyone here help?

Comment: kill the space `alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")`

Answer (score 0):

Dont make it to confusing just echo your output html in the ajax.php and so you will get it into the response and on the success of ajax call when you got the response text just write a simple line

```
document.getElementById("subfeature_div").innerHTML = res;
```

if it not works try this

```
document.getElementById("subfeature_div").innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById("subfeature_div").innerHTML = res;
```

if this also not works try this

```
document.getElementById('subfeature_div').innerHTML =document.getElementById('subfeature_div').innerHTML + res;
```